# How to print on stderr with Swift?

Tags: linux, swift, swift2

I'm using Swift 2.2 on Linux and I need to write some debug output on the standard error stream.

Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
import Foundation

public struct StderrOutputStream: OutputStreamType {
    public mutating func write(string: String) { fputs(string, stderr) }
}
public var errStream = StderrOutputStream()

debugPrint("Debug messages...", toStream: &errStream)
```

However, I've upgraded Swift to 2.2.1 but it seems that `Foundation` is no longer available.

How to write on the standard error stream with Swift 2.2.1 (and that'll still work on the next upgrade)?

Comment: I don't have Swift on Linux installed currently, but according to the docs, `import Glibc` should import most of the C library (such as stderr).

Comment: Will it work also on Mac OS? If it's portable it's better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://swift.org/blog/swift-linux-port/:

> **The Glibc Module:** Most of the Linux C standard library is available through this module similar to the Darwin module on Apple platforms.

So this should work on all Swift platforms:

```
#if os(Linux)
    import Glibc
#else
    import Darwin
#endif

public struct StderrOutputStream: OutputStreamType {
    public mutating func write(string: String) { fputs(string, stderr) }
}
public var errStream = StderrOutputStream()

debugPrint("Debug messages...", toStream: &errStream)
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
public struct StderrOutputStream: TextOutputStream {
    public mutating func write(_ string: String) { fputs(string, stderr) }
}
public var errStream = StderrOutputStream()

debugPrint("Debug messages...", to: &errStream) // "Debug messages..."
print("Debug messages...", to: &errStream)      // Debug messages...
```