# How to terminate with non-zero exit status in Swift code

Tags: swift

I have a problem where I have to devide two numbers and if second number is zero then I have to show error message and terminate with nonzero exis status. I am able to show the message and just return using return statement but I have no idea how to return nonzero exit status.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that this is about a command-line program: You can call the `exit()` function from the C standard library:

```
if denominator == 0 {
    print("denominator is zero")
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```

If you want to print the message to the standard error then use

```
if denominator == 0 {
    fputs("denominator is zero\n", stderr)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```

(or use the approach from [How to print on stderr with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249787/how-to-print-on-stderr-with-swift/37251423#37251423)). An alternative is

```
if denominator == 0 {
    fatalError("denominator is zero")
}
```

which  prints a diagnostic message to the standard error and terminates the program with a non-zero exit status.